# Is there a way to globally apply top attribute to cfdump/writeDump when dealing with ORM objects?

Tags: orm, coldfusion, cfml, cfdump

When dealing with nested ORM relations, using [cfdump](http://cfdocs.org/cfdump) or [writeDump](http://cfdocs.org/writeDump) can rapidly result in `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` errors because CF attempts to resolve relations in nested objects and dump too many objects.

This can be avoided with the `top` attribute, for example: `<cfdump var=#SomeObject# top=3 />`

It's a pain to remember to write this all the time - is there any way to configure CF to not go down too many levels when dealing with ORM objects?

Answer (score 5):

There doesn't appear to be any administrator settings for this. ([issue raised](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3607057))

An imperfect solution is to create a wrapper for the cfdump tag by renaming `{cfusion}/wwwroot/WEB-INF/cftags/dump.cfm` to (for example) `origdump.cfm` then creating a new `dump.cfm` file containing:

```
<cfif isObject(attributes.var) AND NOT StructKeyExists(attributes,'top')>
    <cfset attributes.top = 3 />
</cfif>

<cforigdump attributecollection=#attributes# />

<cfexit method="exitTag" />
```

Fortunately, the writeDump function will call this wrapper (so it works for both tag and function).

Unfortunately the wrapper is not called recursively - if the ORM object is in a struct or array then the original problem still manifests itself - it may be possible to pre-scan complex variables to determine if there are relationships inside and set an appropriate top value, but only a limited solution could be achieved with this (i.e. it would affect neighbouring structs/arrays).

Comment: That was the solution I was about to recommend. I'm not quite seeing the recursion problem when desk-checking this in my head (which I guess is not desk-checking, per se). Recursive calls to `dump.cfm` from within `origdump.cfm` would be passing a `top` attribute to the `dump.cfm` call would it not? So for argument's sake your initial call to `dump.cfm` has no `TOP` param, but it calls `origdump.cfm` with `top=3`. `origdump.cfm` then internally calls `dump.cfm`, passing `top=3`, which your `dump.cfm` wrapper respects, no probs. Or do I need to get the pen and paper out and desk-check properly?

Comment: Sorry, not sure I explained it too well. The wrapper is only called for the top level - i.e. if you do `<cfdump var=#[obj1,obj2]# />` then the top condition fails (var is array, not object), and the check is _not_ performed for the array's children. So the top check would need to be updated to look for containers (arrays/structs) then check their child nodes and set top appropriately, except doing that would not work for situations like `{one:object,two:[[[[a,b,c]]]]}`  because the full contents of two would fail to display. Make sense?

Comment: (Of course, that's only an issue when there are non-object values at a depth of object+3 - not sure how common an occurrence that is in general.)